# Modulo (%) does not work in macro

Tags: c, arrays, macros, modulo

Tried to use a macro instead of a small function to acces an Array on position "index mod 256":

```
static uchar08 ACC_MOD_256(uchar08 * buf, ulong32 index)
{
    return buf[index % 256];
}
```

This works fine and just as expected.

```
#define ACC_MOD_256(arr, ind)   (arr[ind % 256])
```

However the modulo (%) seems not to be working when the code is used as a macro.
The first time the index gets over 255, I get a stack overflow.

I'm quite new to macros, so forgive me if I made an obvious mistake here.

EDIT:
MCVE, as asked:

```
#define ACC_MOD_256(arr, ind)   (arr[(ind) % 256])

int main()
{
    int value;
    int array[256] = {0};

    fillArray(array);


    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
        value = ACC_MOD_256(array, i + 3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can see now, thanks to squeamish ossifrage, that the macro will parse this line:

```
value = arr[i + 3 % 256];
```

Which apparently is equivalent to:

```
value = arr[i + (3 % 256)];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
value = arr[i + 3];
```

Which will fail once 'i + 3' is bigger than the array.

Comment: Please show the use case for the macro where this fails. The meaning of the modulo operator doesn't change in a macro.

Comment: You should put brackets around the argument (i.e., `(ind) % 256` instead of `ind % 256`), but this question isn't really much use without a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please [MCVE] Please.

Comment: Thanks to squeamish ossifrage, this solved my problem. I can see where my mistake was (quite an obvious one).